# When will Swift 2 and xcode 7 be officially released ? I couldn't find a downloadable link for it

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I found many questions and comments related to Swift 2 and xcode 7
I tried to look it up on AppStore but I found nothing but xcode 6.4!
where can I find it ?

Comment: There is no official dates.

Comment: However if you have a link for downloading beta release please put it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is pre-release software it is not yet available through the App Store. Apple have never (as far as I know) given a date when it will be released.

You can however download the pre-release version from Apple's developer site:

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

As with any pre-release software, the usual warnings apply; don't install/use this as your primary tool. Apple have not yet started accepting App Store submissions from Xcode 7.

Comment: And you have to be a licensed Apple developer in order to download pre-released software. Apple has been loosening their restrictions on beta tools lately, but as far as I know this is still a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

2015-Sep-16 is the posted date for Xcode 7:
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/